# Can we use IndexedDB storage client-side in ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, indexeddb

I have got the error saying **"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' "**, when I try to write the IndexedDB codings in my .aspx files.. Will the .aspx pages accept IndexedDB concepts or not??.. If not, then how can I store my SQL server to my local browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDB is [fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) in IE10 and IE11, the latest versions of IE.

Are you perhaps in an IE10 environment? Because if you're in IE10, you can't use the [`addEventListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and should use the [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method instead.

Comment: Thanks for improving my answer. That's great news because most of the IDB docs I see on the web use `addEventListener`